# insertNewObjectForEntityForName returns a different type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am creating a new object based on a class.  In the object model the class is using DocuSignConfig as the type:

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([DocuSignConfig class]) inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]
```

However in my unit test this fails:

```
XCTAssertTrue([config isMemberOfClass:[DocuSignConfig class]]);
```

When I run the unit test in the debugger I get a weird result from the first call.  It's DocuSignConfig_DocuSignConfig_*

The code works and all the properties are there...  Why does the unit test fail then?

Answer (score 0):

Core Data creates a dynamic subclass of your `NSManagedObject` subclass at runtime that provides the implementation for all of the @dynamic properties.

The `isMemberOfClass:` method only tests if the instance is an instance of that class. Instead, use the `isKindOfClass:` method, which also returns true when the instance is a subclass of the provided class.